# Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose $N,H,K \subset G$ are subgroups such that $NH=G$ and $(N \cap H)K=G$. Prove that $N(K \cap H)=G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose $N,H,K \subset G$ are subgroups such that $NH=G$ and $(N \cap H)K=G$. Prove that $N(K \cap H)=G$.

I have no idea. Give me some hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: try to show $|G/N|=|N(K\cap H)/N|$ using the [product formula](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Product_formula) by computing various different expressions for the same quantity, equating them and rearranging them.

> Use $G=(N\cap H)K$ to compute $|G/H|$ and use *that* to compute $|G/K|=|H/(K\cap H)|$, then directly compute from $G=(N\cap H)K$ an additional formula for $|G/K|$. Equate the resulting expressions for $|G/K|$, rewrite via $|A/B|=|C/D|\Leftrightarrow |A/C|=|B/D|$, and then rewrite both sides again using $G=NH$ to obtain $|G/N|=|N(K\cap H)/N|$.

Comment: Why can compute $G/N$? $N$ is not normal in $G$

Comment: @user111636 It doesn't matter if $N$ is normal or not. If you wish, take $|G/N|$ to be shorthand for $|G|/|N|$. Otherwise $G/N$ still makes sense as a coset space. As for why compute it, well, because this is the first thing I got to actually work after a page's worth of $G,N,H,K$s.

Comment: Why $|G/K|=|H/(K∩H)|$?

Comment: @user111636 See the first part of the sentence. Use $N\cap H\subseteq H$ and $G=(N\cap H)K$ to compute $|G/H|$ first.

Comment: $|G/H|=|(N∩H)K/H|$

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: If $G=(N\cap H)K\subseteq HK$ then $G=HK$ so $|G/H|$ is...?

Comment: $|HK/H|=|K/(H \cap K)|$

Comment: And $|G/K|=|HK/K|=|H/(H \cap K)|$

Comment: Yep. That finishes the first half of that sentence. Now compute $|(N\cap H)K/K|$ directly, again using the product formula with $N\cap H$ and $K$.

Comment: On the other hand $|G/K|=|(N \cap H)K/K|= |(N \cap H)/(N \cap H \cap K)|$

Comment: So $|(N∩H)/(N∩H∩K)|=|H/(H∩K)| $

Comment: and $|H/(N \cap H)|=|(H \cap K)/(N∩H∩K)|$

Comment: So we have $|HN/N|=|N(H∩K)/N|$

Comment: Yep! Good job! ${}$